# Get default TitleBar height programmatically before a titlebar is created?

Tags: c#, uwp, titlebar, custom-titlebar

I am creating a custom title bar for my uwp app. I want to match the height of the system bar.

I *might* be able to get that height be calling

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.Height
```

But that depends on a lot of things. The title bar may not have been sized yet.

I've also seen a suggestion (from winforms) to look at the difference of the y coordinates of the window top and the content view top. But again that seems fishy. For one thing, once I've set ExtendViewIntoTitleBar to true, I don't think the method would work.

Is there reliable way to programmatically get the default height?

Comment: Consider reading of this 2 articles: http://blog.thomasnigro.fr/2015/08/07/how-to-compute-the-titlebar-height-on-windows-10/ & https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=1952

Comment: `reliable to get programmatically the default height` -> the problem of this thing is that You have multiple devices that can run UWP, so also the default height will be different on each device. Also there might be different objects in the title bar once the layout is fully loaded, which means the heigh would get resized & this can't be counted before (except going throught all the child elements and get its size). Therefore I would go with the idea of counting this from the `WindowSize` - `ViewSize`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this answer might not be useful to the person who initially asked, at this point of time, but I would still like to suggest the answer:

You can register a handler for when the size of title bar changes. (The docs mention size change, but it may only be the caption button offset and not height)
**This piece of code works well for me, at least at the moment**

```cs
//Put the below line in the Page initialization/OnNavigated function
var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
coreTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged += CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged;

private void CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar sender, object args)
{
     MyAppTitleBar.Height = sender.Height;
}
```

The above code calls your function (`CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged`) automatically whenever the dimensions of the titleBar change (like change in DPI). Here, `MyAppTitleBar` is a `Grid` I made for my custom title bar.

Futher info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar)